# How can the Bolt power miss?

Tags: powers, savage-worlds-adventure-edition

The Core Rulebook page 151 (Activation) implies that the *bolt* power can miss:

> A character activates a power by picking a target within Range and making an arcane skill roll. A roll less than 4 means the power doesn't activate.
>
> A roll of 4 or higher means the power activates and consumes all the Power Points allocated to it, even if it misses the target (such as with *bolt*), or the defender resists.

So, you make an arcane skill roll, but the power (*bolt* specifically) can still miss even after the roll scores a hit. How can that be?

Let's see the *bolt* power description:

> Bolt sends damaging bursts of energy, streaks of holy light, or shards of matter toward one’s foes.
> There are no Range penalties, but the arcane skill roll is affected by Cover, Illumination, and all other usual penalties.
> The damage of the bolt is 2d6, or 3d6 with a raise.

The power description does not say something like "roll Shooting to make a ranged attack", so you aren't supposed to make another roll. Instead, the arcane skill roll seems to be the very roll the caster makes for the ranged attack. So, if the arcane skill roll was successful, how can this attack miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Attack Penalties

The arcane skill roll is both the activation roll (TN 4) and the attack roll. Penalties that affect the casting, and can prevent the power from activating, are Wounds, Fatigue, and other penalties that apply to any power.

Penalties to arcane ranged attacks (Cover, Illumination, Arcane Resistance, *arcane protection*, etc.) still apply to determine if you hit the target, and if the trappings allow casting against adjacent targets you still have to hit the Parry of adjacent targets.

As the *bolt* power notes (emphasis added):

> There are no Range penalties, but the arcane skill roll is affected by **Cover**, **Illumination**, and **all other usual penalties**.

Comment: So one skill roll, but it’s modified separately as a casting roll and as an attack roll? That’s kinda weird. Is that explicitly described anywhere? Because that’s a very non-Savage alteration to the core mechanic.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie  It's a single roll that does two tasks. One task is to activate the magic, the other task is to affect the target. That's how **all powers work** in Savage Worlds. That's been true for every edition of the rules.

Comment: Yes, that part isn’t strange. The part about using the dice results twice with different modifiers is unusual though.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie No it isn't. It happens all the time. Sweep is a single roll compared to the Parry of every target, modified by the conditions that apply to each individual target. If *entangle* is used on a target with Arcane Resistance or *arcane protection* then the casting result may mean the power worked but that the total was insufficient to affect the target - or **one** of the targets when using the Area modifier.

Comment: The roll isn't modified twice: All modifiers affecting the roll are added at once. Powers differ from other rolls only in that they have differentiated failure values: A roll below 4 that is a failure means the power didn't activate. A roll of 4 or above that is a failure means the power activated (using its points) but doesn't affect its targets. This isn't the only differentiated failure rule in the game: Cover Piercing treats rolls close to success differently and Friendly Fire checks for a 1 on the shooting die.

Comment: If the roll isn't modified twice, how can it both hit and miss? @AlienAtSystem *"A roll of 4 or above that is a failure means the power activated (using its points) but doesn't affect its targets"* — how can a ranged attack roll be a failure when it hits 4?

Comment: @enkryptor Let's give an example: You cast a Bolt while having 2 Wounds (-2) at a target behind good cover (-2). Total penalty to the roll is -4, or equivalently, you need to roll an 8 with your dice. Now, based on the numbers of your dice, the results are as follows. 1-3: Bolt is not cast successfully; 4-5: Bolt is cast, but goes off into the landscape. 6-7: Bolt is cast, hits the cover, cover toughness gets added as armor to the target. 8-11: Bolt is cast, hits target. 12+: Bolts is cast, hits with a raise.

Comment: @AlienAtSystem this example is definitely "using the dice results twice with different modifiers", as SevenSidedDie said. It also assumes 1-3 result is better than 4-5 (since you don't waste power points), which is super weird. I can't believe this is actually how the rules are intended to work.

Comment: I would agree that it's weird, (it gets even weirder because you can Aim your Bolt, but it only has any effect when you have any penalty going on), but that is RAW, to the best of my knowledge. On my table, I basically houseruled that part out and have Bolt and Burst always work, with the Arcane Roll simply replacing the Shooting roll (so Burst can actually deviate from target like other AoE attacks).

Comment: I'm not sure it's super weird. It's practically adding one more effect to the failure-success range. We already have critical failure (double 1s), standard failure, success (and success with raise(s)). All this does is specify that a simple failed roll (roll < 4) does not result in Power Point expenditure because the Power doesn't even activate.